# How to avoid nested subscriptions in Angular / RxJS - One call after another call (sequentially / not parallel) And looping http api calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, nested-loops, angular-httpclient, angular2-observables

I have a `situation to make a nested rest api call` from angular.
I have to make `one call after another call based on the result` of previous call as given below

```
  OuterLoop: while (1) {
    getHttpResponse1().subscribe((value1) => {
      if (value1 == 'A') {
        InnerLoop: while (1) {
          getHttpResponse2().subscribe((value2) => {
            if (value2 == 'B') {
              break OuterLoop;
            } else {
              continue InnerLoop
            }
          })
        }
      }else {
        continue OuterLoop;
      }
    })
  }
```

I need make http call in `first loop infinite time` `util` i get `expected result`, once i received the expected result then I need to make `another http call (second loop) infinite time` `util` i get `expected result` after that i have to break all loops.

I have `tried below code` which ok for one http call but I want to make another one based on the result of first one, I end up in nested subscription again.

```
    const sub1 = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {       // http call every second 
      this.apiservice.getHttpResponse1()
        .pipe(takeWhile(val => val))                    // receive true / false
        .subscribe(val => {                             // if true or ignored
          console.log("loopOne" + val)
          sub1.unsubscribe()

          const sub2 = interval(1000).subscribe(() => { // http call every second 
            this.apiservice.getHttpResponse2()
              .pipe(takeWhile(val2 => val2))            // receive true / false
              .subscribe(val2 => {                      // if true or ignored
                console.log("loopTwo" + val2)
                sub2.unsubscribe()
              })
          })
        })
    })
  }
```

Is `this the only approach` ? I felt it's kind of mess. and so on and I felt
`switchMap, mergeMap are inappropriate` for my problem.

I want to `avoid nested subscription / http calls`?

Do you have `any better solution` ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you're on the right track. To flatten the nested subscriptions you need to use `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, or `concatMap` operator.

These operators allow you to manage your subscriptions flow.

A short explanation of the difference between these operators:

`mergeMap` – this operator is best used when you wish to flatten an inner observable but want to manually control the number of inner subscriptions.

`switchMap` – when the operator gets a value, it switches to another observable and cancels the previous one.

`concatMap` – on each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is canceled and the new observable is subscribed.

Your current implementation will look like that:

```js
interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    // when we get value from the interval => make a request
    mergeMap(() => this.apiservice.getHttpResponse1()),
    takeWhile(val1 => val1),
    // when we get the desired value, switch to the next interval
    switchMap(() => interval(1000)),
    // when we get value from the interval => make a request
    mergeMap(() => this.apiservice.getHttpResponse2()),
    takeWhile(val2 => val2),
  ).subscribe();
```

**P.S.**
In this example, `switchMap` can be replaced with any other mapping operator, since the previous subscription is cancelled via `takeWhile`.

**P.P.S.**
The thing you do here is called *long polling*. You can find many interesting approaches on google on how to better organise these looped requests.

Comment: thanks, let me check